# Make an electromagnet attract and repel

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, electromagnetic

I bought an electromagnet online hoping to make it attract and repel metals by changing the polarity of the voltage on it, but I ended up experiencing attraction all the time.

Is there any way to make an electromagnet that attracts in one way and repels in another way?

Comment: The only thing that you can "repulse" with an electromagnet is another magnet.

Comment: @DaveTweed one may also repel superconductors under suitable conditions.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: That's because a superconductor becomes an (electro)magnet when pushed into an existing magnetic field.

Comment: @DaveTweed no, a superconductor excludes all magnetic fields from itself. It is not itself magnetized. Some types of superconductor are capable of flux pinning, but the effect is different and will not lead to repulsion.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: A superconductor excludes a magnetic field by allowing a current to flow, which creates a new field that exactly balances the external field at the surface of the superconductor. I call that a magnet.

Comment: @DaveTweed I suppose so, in the sense that diamagnetism is a type of magnetism. In that case we can say that most materials can be repelled from a (sufficiently strong) magnet.

Answer (score 5):

For a magnet to repulse something, that something needs to also be magnetized and the like poles of the two magnets aligned.

The electromagnet attracted everything magnetic because those other things weren't polarized with their own magnetic fields.  Two electromagnets, or the electromagnet with a permanent magnet would work.

Comment: If I have an electromagnet with an iron core, and I align it was a strong neodymium magnet with it so as to repeal, is it possible for the neodymium magnet to reverse the domains in the core and stick to it if I bring it close enough?

Comment: @blueether No. The worst that can happen is that the neodymium magnet will flip polarity itself, but then you will need a very strong electromagnet.

Answer (score 3):

A coil that is energized with alternating current will repel a conductive but not magnetic ring.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Reversing the polarity on an electro-magnet will reverse its poles but it will still be a magnet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNp8Ss.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Reversing polarity on electromagnet reverses poles.*

Thought experiment: if you had purchased a bar magnet and found that one end of it attracted metals, would you have expected the other end to repel?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFRNmW.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Unlikes attract. Likes repel.*

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make an electromagnet repel a permanent magnet. To accomplish this the electromagnet's current needs to induce a magnetic field "He" in the core which is stronger then the opposite field Hm that the magnet is inducing on that same core. If |He| > |Hm| then the core is magnetized by He-Hm, a net field whose polarity depends on the direction of the applied current. Normally a pretty strong current is required to overcome Hm, making it appear that the magnet always attracts the core.